# How to replace the Laplace variable in a transfer function with a number/value? T(s) -> T(jw)?

Tags: matlab

Was wondering how I could achieve this in Matlab:

T(s) = 1/(s+1) -> T(jw) = 1/(jw+1)

Setting s = jw doesn't help.

For better understanding:

R(s) = some transfer function
L(s) = some transfer function

T(s) = R(s) * L(s)

value_at_jw = T(jw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to evaluate your transfer function at a certain frequency.
The result would be a complex number.

You can't just substitute `s` with a frequency, you would need to create a polynomial or an anonymous function out from your denominator and numerator. Which is one way, an interesting one.  Another very simple way is to use the outputs of the `bode` function:

Imagine a transfer function `G` and a frequency value `jw` you want to insert for 's':

```
G = tf([2 1 ], [1 1 1])
jw = 1i*2000    % or easier without the complex "i"

G =

    2 s + 1
  -----------
  s^2 + s + 1
```

Now you want to know magnitude and phase for the frequency `s = jw`

```
[mag,phase] = bode( G, imag(jw) )     % or just w
```

The rest is math, you now have magnitude and phase=angle of your complex result. A complex number of form **z = a + bi** can be created as follows:

```
z = mag*( cos(phase)+1i*sin(phase) )
```

returns:

```
z =  -4.3522e-04 - 9.0032e-04i
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Matlab's [control systems toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/control/) installed ($$$), you can do a sort of symbolic computations by defining transfer functions, either by giving the polynomial coefficients with [tf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) or as a system factored in poles and zeros using [zpk](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/zpk.html):

```
>> R = tf([1], [1, 1])

Transfer function:
  1
-----
s + 1

>> L = zpk([1,2],[3,4,5], 6)

Zero/pole/gain:
  6 (s-1) (s-2)
-----------------
(s-3) (s-4) (s-5)
```

You can convert between these two formats, and they can be used for simple math:

```
>> R * L

Zero/pole/gain:
     6 (s-1) (s-2)
-----------------------
(s+1) (s-3) (s-4) (s-5)
```

A complex frequency response, finally, can be obtained using [freqresp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/freqresp.html):

```
>> f = logspace(-2, 2, 200);
>> frequency_response = squeeze(freqresp(T, f, 'Hz'));
>> subplot(211)
>> loglog(f, abs(frequency_response))
>> subplot(212)
>> semilogx(f, angle(frequency_response))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways.

```
wmax = 20;
dw = 0.1;
w = -wmax:dw:wmax;
T = 1./(1 + j*w);

subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
grid on
p = plot(w, abs(T))
title('Magnitude')

subplot(2,1,2)
hold on
grid on
p = plot(w, angle(T))
title('Phase')

// or

H = freqs(1, [1 1], w);

figure
subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
grid on
p = plot(w, abs(H))
title('Magnitude')

subplot(2,1,2)
hold on
grid on
p = plot(w, angle(H))
title('Phase')
```

The result is, of course, identical

[image: Bode plot]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I know I can just write the function with T(jw). But I multiply some transfer functions in my script and in the end result I want to replace s with jw.